# Could I join threads in a better way?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Suppose I have multiple Runnable instances in a program, all dispatched by an Executor instance. Further, suppose I at some point need to wait for a subset of these runnables to finish before moving on.

One way I could do this is the following:

```
public abstract class Joinable implements Runnable {

    private final Semaphore finishedLock = new Semaphore(1);

    @Override
    public final void run() {
        try {
            finishedLock.acquireUninterruptibly();
            doWork();
        } finally {
            finishedLock.release();
        }
    }

    public abstract void doWork();

    public void join() {
        finishedLock.acquireUninterruptibly();
    }
}
```

Implementing classes can then simply override doWork(), rather than run(), in order to define what should be done during execution.

The joining  process will then simply look like this:

```
void doStuff() {

    Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    List<Joinable> joinables = new LinkedList<Joinable>();
    // Fill joinables with implementors of Joinable...

    List<Runnable> others = new LinkedList<Runnable>();
    // Fill others with implementors of Runnable...

    for(Joinable joinable : joinables) 
        executor.execute(joinable);

    for(Runnable runnable : others) 
        executor.execute(runnable);

    for(Joinable joinable : joinables) 
        joinable.join();

    // Continue, no matter what the threads in others are up to.
}
```

Is this a good way to solve this problem (is it even safe?), or is there a better one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current solution is not thread safe.  There are no guarantees that the executor will call `run` on your `Joinable` before you call `join`.  Thus, in certain cases, your main thread will acquire the lock before your `Joinable` does.

On possible solution would be instead to use a `CountDownLatch` if you know the total number of joinables `N`, you create a `CountDownLatch(N)` and pass it to each instance.  When each joinable is finished, have it call `countDown()`.  Your main thread calls `await()` on the latch.  `await()` doesn't return until the latch count is 0.

Comment: I like the other answer as well, but went with this one as it went well with the overall design of my project.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a good way to solve this problem (is it even safe?)

This is not quite right.  You can't join on a `Runnable` that you are executing by the `ExecutorService`.  If you want to use a list then do something like this:

```
List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();
for(Joinable joinable : joinables) {
   // this submit returns a `Future`.
   futures.add(executor.submit(joinable));
}
// submit others to the executor _without_ adding to the futures list

for (Future<?> future : futures) {
    // this can throw ExecutionException which wraps exception thrown by task
    future.get();
}
```

> or is there a better one?

If you were waiting for *all* tasks to complete then you could use the `ExecutorService.awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` method.  For example:

```
executor.awaitTerminate(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

But I don't see any better way to do this if you are waiting for a subset of tasks.

Comment: I know, unfortunately I need to clarify the question a bit:

I am not looking at a situation where I only have ONE kind of Runnable instances dispatched by the same executor. Say for example that I have 12 instances of one kind, and 6 of another, and I only want to wait for the first 12 to finish before moving on, regardless of what the state of the other 6 are at that moment. In that case I cannot use awaitTermination.

Comment: I've added some more details about using the `Future` returned by `submit(...)` method @chrsva.